# Write PQ' in the form A'+B

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to find the negation of the sentence "All domestic cars are good".
The sentence can be rewritten as "If a car is domestic, it is good".

if P then Q is the boolean expression - P'+Q.  The negation of P'+Q is PQ', but I can't make a sentence from that expression. So I'm trying to convert it back into "If.. then.. " form to make a sentence.

Hence the question. If you think PQ' can be written as a sentence, I will consider that as an answer as well.

Comment: "Some domestic cat is bad."

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting the quantifiers: if $P(x)$ is '$x$ is domestic', and $Q(x)$ is '$x$ is good', the rewritten original sentence is $\forall x\big(P(x)\to Q(x)\big)$. This can be rewritten as $\forall x\big(\neg P(x)\lor Q(x)\big)$. The negation of this is $\neg\forall x\big(P(x)\to Q(x)\big)$, which is equivalent to

$$\exists x\Big(\neg\big(\neg P(x)\lor Q(x)\big)\Big)$$

and hence to

$$\exists x\big(P(x)\land \neg Q(x)\big)\;.$$

In words, assuming that the universe of discourse is the set of cars, so that there's no need to specify formally that any entity is a car, this is *There is a car that is domestic and not good* or, more idiomatically, *There is a domestic car that is not good*.

Comment: Why is the negation of "for all X, Y" "there exists X where !Y" and not "no X exists such that Y" ?

Comment: @shishir: Think about it: the negation of *For all x, x is alive* is clearly *There is an x that is not alive*: it takes only **one** thing that is not alive to disprove the original assertion. The statement that *No x is alive* is much stronger.

Comment: It's much stronger, but it's also a negation. I'm looking for a negation of the statement, not to disprove it. That's why I turned to boolean algebra.

Comment: @shishir: Every negation is equivalent to the one that I gave. Your stronger statement is ***not*** a negation of the original: it’s too strong to be the negation. It’s simply incompatible with with the original statement, meaning that they cannot both be true. As an example, the negation of $x=1$ is $x\ne 1$. The statement $x=2$ contradicts the statement $x=1$ but is ***not*** the negation of $x=1$.